# Array of checkboxes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is 'FoodType' model which are describes types of food in restaurants. I need to make view for creating a new restaurant, and I need to have list of checkboxes in order to allow user to setup types of food for each restaurant. I want to have something like this:

```
        <% FoodType.all.each do |food_type| %>
                    ...
            <div class="row">
                <%= f.check_box :food_types[0] %>       
            </div>
                    ...
        <% end %>
```

I want to have parameters like `params[restaurant][food_types][0] = true` in order to make some actions after creating. Please, tell me, how can I do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should include your whole form in order to help you fix your issue easier.  also include the code in the action.  there's an easy way to do this but you have to follow conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you have a join table which joins restaurants and food types?  Let's say that you have one called `restaurant_food_types` (with a model RestaurantFoodType), which has `restaurant_id` and `food_type_id`?

You will then have this association in restaurants:

```
Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :restaurant_food_types
  has_many :food_types, :through => :restaurant_food_types
```

This will give you the method .food_type_ids which you can call on a restaurant to set the joins.  It's this method that you should hook into in your form: it expects an array of ids, so you need to set up an array-style parameter (one where the name ends in [])  You may need to use check_box_tag rather than .check_box, to access an array-style parameter name:  i would do this:

```
<% form_for @restaurant do |f| %>
  <% FoodType.all.each do |food_type| %>
    ...
    <div class="row">
      <%= check_box_tag "restaurant[food_type_ids][]", food_type.id, @restaurant.food_type_ids.include?(food_type.id) %><%= food_type.name %>    
    </div>
    ...
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "Save" %>
<% end %>
```

Like i say i'm using a check_box_tag here but there might be a nicer way to hook into the food_type_ids method.